# Subtracting multiple columns in R

Tags: r, loops, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have a df of 300 columns that are name N0, N1, N2, N3 ... N300. All values are numeric (no NAs). I want to subtract N1-N0 into a new column, we will name this column x. Then I want to subtract N2-X to get a new column that will be subsequently use as N3-last subtraction.
here is an example

```
N0   N1  N2
1     2   3
0     1   2
1     1   0
```

first step : N1-N0= x

```
X
-
1
1
0
```

second step: N2-X = Y

```
Y
-
2
1
0
```

And so on...  keep doing this for my 300 columns!

Well thanks in advance!

Comment: So, you want `N300 - (N299 - (N298 - ... (N2 - (N1 - N0))...))`?

Comment: Yeap! That is a way to put it!

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
nc = ncol(df)
nc_odd = seq(1, nc, by = 2)
nc_even = seq(2, nc, by = 2)
result = rowSums(df[, nc_even]) - rowSums(df[, nc_odd])
if(nc %% 2 == 1) result = -result # flip sign if there is an odd number of columns
```

Explanation:

`N300 - (N299 - (N298 - ... (N2 - (N1 - N0))...))` is the same as `(N300 + N298 + N296 + ... + N2 + N0) - (N299 + N297 + ... + N1)`. All the even columns end up with the same sign, and all the odd columns end up with the same sign. Whether those signs are positive or negative depends on the total number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy option by using `Reduce`:

```
res <- Reduce(function(x,y) y-x,df)
```

such that

```
> res
[1] 2 1 0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(N0 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), N1 = c(2L, 1L, 1L), N2 = c(3L, 
2L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: With `accumulate = TRUE` and some transposing or other solutions if OP wants to actually have all columns. Also first one may be just subtracting the 0s, +1 otherwise

Comment: @arg0naut91 Thanks! I am not sure if OP wants all columns along the successive subtractions, so I just provide the approach to get the final one. Otherwise OP can use `Reduce` as you said

Answer (score 1):

An option with `reduce`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(df, ~ .y - .x)
#[1] 2 1 0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(N0 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), N1 = c(2L, 1L, 1L), N2 = c(3L, 
2L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```